# Oracle Tracing Activity of Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql

Our legacy application has over 4000+ triggers.

In order to diagnose a bug, we have to trace which trigger(s) inserted records into a particular table.

Had the legacy triggers logged their activity into a common table, we could have easily traced the activity on a particular table.

But this is not how the triggers were coded.

Is there a way to setup some kind of auditing process to trace following activity on the table :

```
 a. which trigger inserted record into the table
 b. what was the statement
 c. when the activity took place.
```

Since this is a development environment - we are not too concerned about performance implications.

thanks all.

Comment: What version of Oracle is this for?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

Enable auditing as:

`alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;`

Restart the database for the above to take effect.

Then enable auditing on the table:

`audit insert on schema.table by access;`

Then view the audit records in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`. This gives you `b.` and `c.`. Using `SQL_TEXT`, you can find the SQL in `V$SQL`, and in `V$SQL`, the `PROGRAM_ID` (=`OBJECT_ID` in `DBA_OBJECTS`) and `PROGRAM_LINE#` columns tell you where that statement came from.